# Sql Query for inserting data from 2 tables into one based on name

Tags: sql

Hello I currently 2 tables of data from different sources,
I need to combine all of them into one main table.

**Database layout**:
**Table A**
-Name
-Ranking
-Score

**Table B**
-Name
-Ranking
-Score

**Table New**
-Name
-Ranking A
-Score A
-Ranking B
-Score B

I want to take the data from table A and B and insert it into table New based on the name.
Not sure how to do this in sql, any help appreciated

Comment: Do all the names exist in both tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming every record in TableA has a corresponding record in TableB:

```
insert into TableNew
    (Name, RankingA, ScoreA, RankingB, ScoreB)
    select a.Name, a.Ranking, a.Score, b.Ranking, b.Score
        from TableA a
            inner join TableB b
                on a.Name = b.Name
```

If that assumption is invalid, then:

```
insert into TableNew
    (Name, RankingA, ScoreA, RankingB, ScoreB)
    select a.Name, a.Ranking, a.Score, b.Ranking, b.Score
        from TableA a
            left join TableB b
                on a.Name = b.Name
    union all
    select b.Name, a.Ranking, a.Score, b.Ranking, b.Score
        from TableB b
            left join TableA a
                on b.Name = a.Name
        where a.Name is null
```

Comment: Isn't a `UNION ALL` with a `WHERE a.Name IS NULL` in the second query more efficient?

Comment: used this example to solve a similar problem where I wanted values in one table to be able to override the values in the other (if they existed). I Just had to incorporate coalesce() in my select stmt - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this(should work in Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL):
To Create the third table(if it doesn't exist):

```
CREATE TABLE [TableNew] AS
SELECT  a.Name
                ,a.Ranking RankingA
                ,a.Score ScoreA
                ,b.Ranking RankingB
                ,b.Score ScoreB
  FROM  TableA a, TableB b
 WHERE  a.Name = b.Name
```

To Insert into third table(if it exists):

```
INSERT INTO [TableNew]
SELECT  a.Name
                ,a.Ranking RankingA
                ,a.Score ScoreA
                ,b.Ranking RankingB
                ,b.Score ScoreB
  FROM  TableA a, TableB b
 WHERE  a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with an implicit join in such a small query.